# import data from vertica to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I try to upload data from Vertica to Hive by using Sqoop.
I can see that it creates a file and a table on HIVE, but when i try to select the data from the HIVE or from the file i cannot see the data. it shows me an ERROR(there is no delimiter on the column of the file) select.

this is my code:

```
sqoop import -m -1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://serverName:5443/DBName" --username "user" --password "pass" --query 'select id, name from contacts limit 10' --target-dir "folder/contacts" --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table db.contacts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these arguments and choose a delimiters for your data

```
--fields-terminated-by
--lines-terminated-by
```

Comment: If that is insufficient, also check: `--lines-terminated-by`